# Import render settings from another .blend file

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, optimization

Is it possible to import render settings (e.g. how many times the light paths bounce for Cycles) from another .blend file? There are too many of them and I don't want to check and copy each one manually.

Comment: you could save it as startup file (in your "from"-blend file, but before save your "original" startup file) and then you have it ;)

Comment: 2nd possibility: just delete all objets/collections and "save" it as "new" blend file

Comment: by the way: i use "template"-blend file for this. These are just "naked" blend file with some settings from which i often start with. E.g.  i have one for video-editing with all these .mov-settings.

Comment: These settings are stored in the scene properties, and you can append them like any other blender object by going File > Append > your file > Scene > your scene

Comment: Yeah I know I can save it as a startup file, but my situation is that I have a .blend file from someone else and I'm trying to copy their render settings. Append scene isn't perfect either because it appends the whole scene (but yeah it makes the copy-paste process easier)